# Setting initial value of modelForm instance

Tags: django, django-forms

Why can't I set `instance = None` in my unbound model form?

```
def sample(request):

    prf_form = ProfileForm(instance=None)
    print prf_form.instance #debugger print
    return render_to_response(template, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I get the following exception:`DoesNotExist`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to instantiate an empty Profile and pass that:

```
profile = Profile()
prf_form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't send it an instance:

```
def sample(request):

    prf_form = ProfileForm()
    return render_to_response(template, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```